# Share one global apscheduler scheduler across all modules Django

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

I need to save apscheduler scheduler instance I'm working with to remove it later or modify.

I have django web app. I have notification model in django admin. After creating a new row - I schedule notification to send it later on my email. And that part works perfectly.

But what if I need to change the notification or delete it?
There is problem..

With some "returns" I've got the schedule instance in my **admin.py**. But I can only print it to console and that's all. How and where can I save this instance to work with it later? (after delete row 4 example).

Comment: can you show the error or what working in console

Comment: I dont have errors, I have apscheduler background scheduler instance(like variable)in my admin.ModelAdmin class. I want to save it somewhere to use later.

Comment: I want to do smth like that(http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules.htm) but with scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just add your scheduler to AppConfig